# Vim keymap para colar algo copiado de fora no modo normal

Tags: vim

Estou tentando fazer um atalho para colar algo copiado de fora para dentro no Vim no modo normal mas não estou conseguindo:

`nnoremap <C-S-p> i<C-S-v><ESC>`

Comment: para inserir texto do clipboard do sistema o comando vim é `"+p` (aspas duplas, mais, p)...no Windows eu também uso Control-Ins para copiar e Shift-Ins para colar...agora, esse Control-Shift-V aí eu não me lembro, acho que não funciona mesmo (a não ser que exista alguma configuração adicional no .vimrc)

Comment: muito obrigado consegui aqui. Na verdade o Ctrl+Shift+V é por que eu uso para colar no terminal do linux. Mas obrigado mesmo valeu

Comment: então escreve como você fez, pode ser útil para outras pessoas